# mysqli real escape string giving blank output

Tags: php

I am trying to inout information from a get form into a database for obvious reason i do not want to risk sql injection so i am using escape string, however when i am trying to use mysqli real escape string it causes a blank output, but when i use plain get it works fine

So far i have managed to display it using echo $cly;
Even when trying adding real escape string direct to the get `mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['cly']);` this to does not work

```
$cly=$_GET['cly'];
$clyesc=mysqli_real_escape_string($cly);
echo $clyesc;
```

Comment: If you don't want to risk SQL injection.... use bind variables with prepared statements rather than mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: [You have to provide a mysqli link as first parameter.](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

Comment: [Prepared statements and bind Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 1):

You will get blank output from `mysqli_real_escape_string` if you don't have a database connection open. This will cause PHP to emit the warning:

> mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in - on line …

Connect to the database first and pass the link to it as the first argument.

That said, you should generally avoid `mysqli_real_escape_string` in favour of prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for more on bound parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the first parameter as the connection object:

```
$cly=$_GET['cly'];
$clyesc=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $cly);
echo $clyesc;
```